# Why is my Rails form helper written improperly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know I've written it wrong, but I'm looking at the documentation and can't figure out how.

My model is `Quote` and has three fields, `body`, `attribution`, and `work`, all strings. The form is intended to add a new quote to a page of quotations.

on `main/index.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(:quote, url: {action: 'create'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
    <%= f.text_field :attribution %>
    <%= f.text_field :work %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

in `main_controller.rb`

```
  def create
    Quote.create(body: params[:body], attribution: params[:attribution], work: params[:work])
  end
```

The form submits, and an entry is saved to the database -- but it's a totally blank entry. I'm not sure why. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Post your `params` when the `form` is submitted

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. The way rails forms are supposed to work, you're not meant to get body, attribution, etc independently, they should be wrapped up into a quote object.  But...
2. In your form, your not properly binding an object to the form the way rails expects. You can read more in the documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object.  You could also generate a fake scaffold `rails generate scaffold HighScore game:string score:integer` to generate a fake model and see an example of how it's supposed to work.  The default scaffolding even has simple examples of how to deal with save errors.
3. Finally, as @Paven suggested, when you get confused, be sure to look at what's going on in your log - i.e. what params are being posted to your create action.  That is always helpful and a good way to diagnose problems quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Your form does't need the `action` argument. The `form_for` helper uses `ActiveRecord objects` to determine the path, meaning as long as you build your object correctly, you won't need to determine your path individually:

```
<%= form_for @quote do |f| %>
```

Secondly, you'll want to look at your `create` method:

```
#app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb
def new
   @quote = Quote.new
end

def create
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
end

private

def quote_params
    params.require(:quote).permit(:body, :attribution, :work)
end
```

---

The problem is you're not sending an `ActiveRecord` object to your `form_for` helper. You can [read the explanation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html):

> In Rails, this is usually achieved by creating the form using form_for
>   and a number of related helper methods. form_for generates an
>   appropriate form tag and yields a form builder object that knows the
>   model the form is about. Input fields are created by calling methods
>   defined on the form builder, which means they are able to generate the
>   appropriate names and default values corresponding to the model
>   attributes, as well as convenient IDs, etc. Conventions in the
>   generated field names allow controllers to receive form data nicely
>   structured in params with no effort on your side.

In order to get the form working correctly, you need to be able to provide a valid ActiveRecord object (`@variable`), which the helper can use to determine the url etc

My code above helps you provide a new `ActiveRecord` variable, and allows you to use it in the form. This should allow the `form_for` method to send your data to the `create` method, which will then create & save an object in the db for you

Comment: You may want to explain some more. With this he'll get it working, but still won't have an idea what is going on.

Comment: Okay! I'll get onto that now